# PySerial: writing to microcontroller using a while loop adds 100ms to the loop time

Tags: python, pyserial, uart

I'm trying to do actuator control with values calculated from Python. I am at a point where I want to send the calculated data to a microcontroller in an infinite loop. It seems like ser.write() adds 100ms (total loop execution time of 120ms)

Right now I'm sending the value obtained by my Python code to a microcontroller using PySerial.
Python's data processing side isn't the problem because I checked that the data was being calculated every 20ms.

Below is the code I am using.

```
import serial as ser
COM = 'COM4'
brate = 115200
ser = ser.Serial()
ser.baudrate=brate
ser.port = COM

while(1):

   ##Data Calculation Code###

   ser.open()
   send = bytearray([int(calculated_data)])
   ser.write(send)
   if(i !=0):
        ser.close()
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out after searching a little bit more.
Seems like the serial port doesn't have to be opened and closed everytime.

```
from serial import Serial
ser = ser.Serial(COM, brate)
```

Did the trick.